# three conditions and one rule to use any domain name in htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these conditions and rule in my htaccess file, and it works and does what it's supposed to do.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/parser.php?(.*)?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.extension$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-.]+)\.mydomain\.extension [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.extension/index/parser.php?%2&domain_name=mydomain.extension [QSA,L]
```

I want to rewrite it so it can work with any domain name pointed at the server, but don't know how. I tried this but it failed. It should only activate on subdomains, not root domains. Also, I am not versed on the whole dollar sign and percentage usage in htaccess files. $1, $2, %1, %2, etc. Never know when dollar or percent should be used, or what number to use after it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/parser.php?(.*)?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-.]+)\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index/parser.php?%2&domain_name=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Edit

Tried this on last line. Still didn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/index/parser.php?%2&domain_name=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Edit

Tried suggestion and it made this:

```
something.tld
```

Go to this:

```
http://tld/index/parser.php?something&domain_name=tld
```

Should be:

```
http://something.tld/index/parser.php?something&domain_name=something.tld
```

Edit

The next version didn't work either. Showed an internal server error page. Same error whether domain.tld was used or subdomain.domain.tld was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/parser.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.|)([a-z0-9-]+)\.(.+\.(?:[a-z]{2}\.[a-z]{2}|[a-z]+))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2/index/parser.php?%1&domain_name=%2 [QSA,L]
```

So this will take a request for:

```
http://www.foo.some-domain.tld/anything
```

and redirect to:

```
http://some-domain.tld/index/parser.php?foo&domain_name=some-domain.tld
```

As far as the backreferences go, the `$` ones backreference groupings made in the rewrite rule, while the `%` ones backrefernce groupings from a rewrite condition.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/intro.html#regex

[image]

Comment: what would redirect url look like if someone went to: http://foo.some-domain.tld?parameter=something

Comment: i tried it and it made this: something.extension go to this: http://extension/index/parser.php?something&domain_name=extension ... should be http://something.extension/index/parser.php?something&domain_name=something.extension

Comment: that edited version shows internal server error message when not using subdomain. just using whatever.com . actually same server error with subdomain as well.

Comment: @leoarce sorry, left out a `)` at the end of the condition

Comment: it's almost looking like that first parser line is not even needed. not quite sure. i'll see if this new version does the trick.